# Generate div id number for Simplepie RSS items

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, simplepie

I'm fetching an RSS feed with Simplepie on a Wordpress blog. Each RSS item has a div container, and I want each one to have a unique id number (something like `<div id="div-#">`).

How would I generate a unique number for each item? Here's the code I'm using:

```
<ul>

<?php include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$rss = fetch_feed(http://www.example.com);
if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) :  
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(6); 
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems); 
    endif; ?>

<?php 
    if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>No items.</li>';
    foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) :  ?>

        <a href="<?php   echo $item->get_link();?>">


        <?php  
                echo '<li><div class="item-headline" id="div-">'.
                $item->get_title().
                '</div><div class="item-info">'.
                $item->get_description().
                '</div></li>';
            ?>

        </a>    

<?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Just pasted the code I'm using. I know it's inelegant, but I'm something of a PHP novice...which is why I don't know how to generate numbers dynamically for each div id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`get_id(true)`](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_id) to get a unique MD5 hash of the item.

```
echo '<li><div class="item-headline" id="div-'.$item->get_id(true).'">'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<?php
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) {
    echo '<div id="item-<?php echo $num ?>">';
    // ...
}
```